# React - define and access environment variables

Tags: reactjs, heroku, environment-variables

I'm deploying a React app (version 15.4.2) to Heroku, but I'm having trouble accessing environment variables - any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

I had initially started this app using `create-react-app`, but ended up ejecting it so that I could exercise a little more control.

In `config/env.js`, I've set the variable that I want, `API_URL`, like so:

```
function getClientEnvironment(publicUrl) {
  var processEnv = Object
    .keys(process.env)
    .filter(key => REACT_APP.test(key))
    .reduce((env, key) => {
      env[key] = JSON.stringify(process.env[key]);
      return env;
    }, {
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(
        process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
      ),
      'PUBLIC_URL': JSON.stringify(publicUrl),
      'API_URL': JSON.stringify(
        process.env.API_URL || 'http://localhost:4000/api/v1'
      )
    });
  return {'process.env': processEnv};
}

module.exports = getClientEnvironment;
```

And this module is referenced in `webpack.config.prod.js` (paraphrasing)...

```
var env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

module: {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(env)
    ]
}
```

Ultimately, I want to reference `API_URL` in a script that I have in `src/static/scripts/fetch.js`:

```
fetch(`${API_URL}${url}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers()
})
.then(parseResponse)
```

But when I tried to push this up to Heroku, it flopped with the error

```
remote:   24:21  error  'API_URL' is not defined  no-undef
```

Have I set the `API_URL` variable incorrectly?  Or perhaps I didn't properly deploy the app?  Although I ejected the app, I still deployed it as one would an unejected `create-react-app` app - https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration - but maybe that's insufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was ultimately able to resolve this issue by restructuring a bit - I got away from using the file structure that emerges after ejecting a `create-react-app` app and just included a `webpack.config.js` file in my app's top-level directory. In that file, I included

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'API_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL || 'http://localhost:4000/api/v1')
    })
]
```

and that took care of it. So this doesn't exactly answer my question, since I ended up changing the file structure around a bit, but it did reslove the problem.

Comment: What you did is OK, and will work. However, be aware that this metohd won't play with Heroku Pipelines. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903164/how-to-access-environment-variables-on-heroku-from-angularjs/42132335#42132335.

Comment: @YoniRabinovitch yes, you're right, and I've actually had that problem.